# Simulating user click in a web page [JAVA]

Tags: java

I am currently working on getting the source code of a specific web page in a file using Java.

The web page is: http://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/ListaAppelliOfferta.do

I wrote some code to do that:

```
 try{
      URL url= new URL("http://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/ListaAppelliOfferta.do");
      URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
      BufferedReader dis= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((url.openStream())));
      String s="";
      while (( s=dis.readLine())!= null) {
      System.out.println(s);
      }
      dis.close();
      }catch (MalformedURLException mue) {}
      catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

}

This works fine.

The problem is I want to "simulate" a user selecting "[1020] Dipartimento di Informatica" in Facoltà and "[1102] Informatica e Tecnologie per la produzione del Software" in Corso di Studio and then the user clicking on "Avvia Ricerca" which starts a search and shows a table with the results.

The goal is obtaining the source code of the web page containing also the information in the table I need.

I noticed that if I manually do those selections and then click "Avvia Ricerca" to start the search, the web page is loaded again showing the data in the table I need, but the URL does not change.

So even if the page is now showing the data I need, when using my code I can only get the source code of the page as it is BEFORE doing the selections and doing the search.

Comment: Have you considered using a library? For example http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ offers a nice way of doing stuff like you are planning to do.

Comment: HtmlUnit (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

I've done similar things with HTMLUnit (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) before, works quite well for simulating anything in regards to websites, and for scraping.

Comment: My goal is obtaining the source code of the entire web page, including the resulting table which is what I need most. I am going to use then XPath for getting the info in it and save to a csv file

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to open the page in a web debugger (Ctrl-Shift-I) and see what URLs are fetched when you make your selections, and then program those fetches in your Java app.
The downside of this approach is if the page implementation changes your code will break.

Another alternative is to run the page Javascript in a browser sandbox. That is also error-prone and can even be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, you just could send this information by GET/POST (for example with url?department=xy), but in your case its quite complicated, as the site uses JSF and generates an ID (and the information, which department is chosen, is written there, for example "http://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/ListaAppelliOfferta.do;jsessionid=365EB9843B2872E73067693A6095BA35").

Depending on what you want to do you could use Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). This simulates the Browser, and you could get your elemeents (for example department by name: fac_id), and set the value (for example with selectByValue after you created a select-element, documented here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html).

If you need to do it without using Selenium (for example cause you need to do it only on command line and without using the browser itself) you can try do deactivate cookies, then the parameters should be sent in GET- or POST-Parameters, and you could inspect this e.g. with Firebug. But thats the harder soluation, Selenium would be much easier to use.